# Ubuntu filesystem breaks after rebooting from Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I've got a Windows 10 UEFI and Ubuntu 17.04 UEFI on a GPT partition system.
Each time I reboot to windows and then try to get back to Ubuntu I get this error:

[image]

So I have to enter these commands to enter to my Ubuntu each time:

```
e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sda7
e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda7
e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sda8
e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda8
```

If I don't switch back to Windows, I won't have any problems with Ubuntu on boot, I tried re-installing Ubuntu and re-partitioning my hard drive but that didn't work.

Comment: In Windows, go to Power Options -> Choose what the power buttons do -> Change settings that are currently unavailable -> Disable “Fast startup (recommended)” and Hibernation.

Comment: I suspect that Windows is messing with your Ubuntu partitions. Are you using any Windows filesystem drivers for ext2/3/4fs? If so, disable them, at least temporarily. If not, please edit your question to show the output of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` in Ubuntu. That will reveal the type codes of your partitions. (Windows might be messing with the Ubuntu partitions if they've got the wrong type codes.)

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your hard disk is broken. Best thing you can do is check the health status in Ubuntu or in Windows.

For Ubuntu for example you can do this with **smartmontools** in the terminal

First install smartmontools:

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```

For short test to see if the harddisk passed the test:

```
sudo smartctl -H /dev/sda
```

Or to show all the output from the test

```
sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda
```

**Alternatively** you can install **GSmartControl** from the Ubuntu Software Store.

If you're stuck in Windows and can not boot in to Ubuntu, there are plenty of applications for checking hard disk health on the web.

Comment: As I read the question, the problem occurs reliably, but *only* after rebooting from Windows. That suggests a problem caused by Windows, not a hardware failure. That said, checking the SMART status will do no harm, so I can't disagree with the suggestion to check it.

Answer (score 0):

As urben mentioned GSmartControl can be used.
If you go online and download a live gparted iso you can boot from it and check the whole hdd this way. I'd do it this way, but also see vendor/smart drive check info.

Alternatively you can use GSmartControl on the Linux portion of hard drive and in windows type in on a command prompt:

```
chkdsk /f c:
```

The problem to me with booting into each OS is that I am not sure that is going to get to your potentially real problem.I say this because those checks do not touch all partitions like boot, efi,and a few others, etc...

With the model of your PC, it may come with a hotkey option to get into a hard drive diagnostic program. This is a good option along with the gparted live boot option.

Going into the bios and disabling "fast boot" if it has that option may help. Although, when your Ubuntu is shutting down and rebooting, and then you get the boot options and choose Windows and then it boots to Windows as you said, but shutting down Windows and booting to Ubuntu is where you get the errors seems unusual to me unless the partition that you have Ubuntu has a bad sector/areas of the drive, or there is some corruption of system files.
I'm no expert, but grub is just an intermediary between the 2 operating systems from what I understand in simplest form. I just points to boot files depending on what OS you choose to boot from.

If you end up having to re-install Ubuntu again, I would do a re-formatting of the hard drive partitions once again before re-installing. ( Not sure what types of re-installs you have already tried)